# dynamic cascade dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've got two dropdowns

1. category
2. subcategory

If a category is selected, then second dropdown should automatically update, so I've written this code below for 1st dropdown:

```
public void bindcategory()
{         
    DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetCate();        
    DropDownList dropdownlist = new DropDownList();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListItem listitem = new ListItem();
        listitem.Text = dr["cate_name"].ToString();
        dropdownlist.Items.Add(listitem);            
    }
    cate_search.Controls.Add(dropdownlist);
}
```

but writing 2nd dropdown code getting some error and also confused that **how could to get the 1st dropdown select value, because 1st dropdown declared inside of bindcategory() block, thats why it couldn't be accessed in other blocks.** So what should I do for that?

```
public void bindsubcategory()
{
     //error (selected cate_id from 1st dropdown cant accessed due to scop problem)
     DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetSubCate(   //some cate_id   ); 

     // what should the code here?
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing few things. See the sample code below

```
public void bindcategory()
{         
    DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetCate();        
    DropDownList dropdownlist = new DropDownList();
    //SET AutoPostBack = true and attach an event handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event. This event will fire when you change any item in the category dropdown list.
    dropdownlist.AutoPostBack = true;
    dropdownlist.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListItem listitem = new ListItem();
        listitem.Text = dr["cate_name"].ToString();
        listitem.Value= dr["cate_id"].ToString();
        dropdownlist.Items.Add(listitem);            
    }
    cate_search.Controls.Add(dropdownlist);
}

void dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //Grab the selected category id here and pass it to the bindSubCategory function.
    bindSubCategory(Convert.ToInt32((sender as DropDownList).SelectedValue)); 
}

public void bindsubcategory(int categoryId)
{
     DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetSubCate(categoryId);
     //Bind this data to the subcategory dropdown list 
}
```